# AngularJS Directives isolated scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning about directives in AngularJS and I came across this code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
//creating custom directive syntax
app.directive("myDir", function () {
return {
        restrict: "E", //define directive type like E = element, A = attribute, C =
        class, M = comment
        scope: { //create a new child scope or an isolate scope
     title: '@' //@ reads the attribute value,
 //= provides two-way bindi
```

My questions are:

According to the code, the attribute 'scope' apparently is used to create either a child scope, or an isolated scope. How do we then differentiate if we want the scope for this directive to be isolated or not? If I only want to have an scope child but not isolated how would I do?

Isolated means that the isolated scope that we are creating cannot access the variables from the parent scope, right?

A parent scope by default cannot access the variables from the child, but a child can access the variables of the parent if this one is not isolated, am I right?

And last question, if we define an attribute 'controller' to specify a controller for this directive, this directive will have by default the scope of the controller?

Thanks!!

Comment: Your understanding of isolated scopes and parent-child scopes is correct. The `controller` for a directive will have the same `$scope` as the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `scope: true` to get a new child scope that isn't isolated.

From the [angular-js docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

> `scope`
>
> **If set to `true`**, then a new scope will be created for this directive.
>   If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only
>   one new scope is created. The new scope rule does not apply for the
>   root of the template since the root of the template always gets a new
>   scope.
>
> **If set to `{}` (object hash)**, then a new "isolate" scope is created. The
>   'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in that it does not
>   prototypically inherit from the parent scope. This is useful when
>   creating reusable components, which should not accidentally read or
>   modify data in the parent scope.